# Expected value of squared uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \text{Unif}(\sqrt n S^{n-1})$ where $S^{n-1}$ is the unit Sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{E}(\left \| X \right \|^2)=n$ .
An interesting fact here is the rotational invariance of the distribution of $X$. I have used it to prove that  $\mathbb{E}( X_i^2)$ is a constant $\alpha$ but I didn't find an argument that helps me determine the constant factor $\alpha$. Does anyone have a hint or an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X \sim \mathcal U(\sqrt{n}S^{n-1})$ then $\mathbb P(X \in \sqrt{n}S^{n-1}) = 1$ that is $X$ is almost surely lying in the set $\{v \in R^n : ||v|| = \sqrt{n} \}$. So that almost surely $||X|| = \sqrt{n}$, from which follows $\mathbb E[||X||^2] = n$